# Unexpected output after typecasting

Tags: c++, c++11

For the following print statement

```
std::cout << 10.1 / 0.1 << " " << (int)(10.1 / 0.1) << std::endl;
```

My understanding is that `(10.1/0.1)` is `101.0` hence after typecasting as an int the result should be `101`. Instead I received `101 100`. Can somebody please explain me why it is so???

Comment: It's because of floating point math. 0.1 is representable as a slightly larger number, and hence the result is slightly less than 101, so truncating will cut it off.

Comment: Please also see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16268154/27678

Comment: One possible hack is to add `0.5` to your floating point number then type-cast. As in `(int)(10.1 / 0.1 + 0.5)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/560648