# Adding two floats resulting in 2 different answers in C

Tags: c

I was writing a program to convert a decimal point numbers into binary and encountered a problem where the code printed a different value on calculation.The values in `wholein` and `fracbin` are correct but the sum seems to be wrong somehow.

CODE:

```
int main(){
    float num,frac,bin,wholebin,fracbin;
    int whole;
    printf("Enter decimal number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);

    whole = (int)(num);
    frac = num - (float)whole;

    wholebin = (float)wholePart(whole);
    fracbin = fracPart(frac);
    
    bin = wholebin + fracbin;
    
    printf("%f : %f : %f : %f", wholebin, fracbin, bin , wholebin + fracbin);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter decimal number: 34.24
100010.000000 : 0.001111 : 100010.000000 : 100010.000000
```

I tried using different compilers, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: The difference between the numbers is too big to fit into one float. Replace float with double and it works.

Comment: What is `wholePart`. You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without your code it is harder to help you.

Comment: @Kane Frame,  For greater insight, add `printf("num:%a frac:%a\n", num, frac);`.  Post the code for `fracPart()` - it is questionable.

Comment: A minimal example of the sum issue would be: `float w = 100010.0; float f = 0.001111; printf("%f + %f = %f ?", w, f, w+f);`.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not specify a representation of floating-point numbers, but it will probably be hard to find a system not using [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

The `float` type (corresponding to IEEE 754 "binary32") has 7 digital significant digits (minimum 6 by the C standard, defined as `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`). In this case, the sum `100010.001111` spans 12 digits and cannot be represented exactly by the `float` type. Instead, it is approximated by the closest representable value which is the result you observe.

The `double` type (corresponding to IEEE 754 "binary64") will provide 15-16 significant digits (minimum 10 by the C standard, defined as `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`) so changing from `float` to `double` solves this problem, but only up to that number of digits. Beyond that a string representation may be considered.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306177/exact-representation-of-floating-points-in-c) or the Wiki link above for details about floating-point representation.